# my script for google's footer doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I'm trying to automate **google's footer** and it runs the script but it doesn't update anything. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Sounds to me like it's an authentication thing.

Someone did something similar?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: Include your script and maybe we can figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Here is a simple example of adding a new paragraph to a footer.

**Script**

```
function editFooter() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let footer = doc.getFooter();
    if( !footer ) footer = doc.addFooter();
    footer.appendParagraph("This is the footer");
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Document.addFooter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addFooter())
- [FooterSection.appendParagraph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section#appendParagraph(String))